# How to not overlap table and rows?

Tags: html, css

When I zoom out the chrome page , HTML table is overlapped , when zoomed that table should not be overlapped with other rows and columns

Please help me in this, thanks in advance

This is my CSS code and my HTML5 code.
When I zoom out the chrome page , HTML table is overlapped when zoomed That table should not be overlapped with other rows and columns.

```css
table {
         background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(240,240,240), rgb(250,250,250));
         font-size: 13px;
         line-height: 14px;
        
 
         .table-header .t-cell {
             color:blue;             
             font-size: 1rem !important;
             cursor: pointer;
         }
 
     }
     .t-cell {         
         width: 10%;
         // width: calc(12% - 5px);
         font-size: 1rem;
         border-top: 0;
         
     }
 
 
     .t-sub-cell {
         width: 11%;
         border-right: 1px solid #ececec;
         border-top: 0 !important;
         padding-left: 1% !important;
         height: 10vh;
     }
 
     .t-sub-header-cell {
         width: 11%;
         border-right: 1px solid #ececec;
         border-top: 0;
         padding-left: 1% !important;
         height: 10vh;
     }
 
     .t-sub-cell1 {
         width: 11%;
         padding-left: 1% !important;
     }
 
     .t-action {
         width: 5%;
         border-top: 0;
     }
 
     .tran-table {
         height: calc(100vh - 250px);
         overflow-y: auto;
     }
 
     .tran-table::-webkit-scrollbar {
         width: 5px;
     }
 
     .tran-table::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
         background: #888; 
     }
 
     .tran-desc {
         font-weight: 600;
     }
 
     .tran-desc-detail {
         width: 200px !important;
         overflow: hidden;
         text-overflow: ellipsis;
         white-space: nowrap;
         display: inline-block;
     }
 
     .table-header {
         border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
     }
 
     .tran-table tr {
         border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
     }
 
     .sub-table-header {
         width: calc(100% - 25px) !important;
         border-left: 1px solid #ececec;
         border-right: 1px solid #ececec;
         border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
         height: 10vh;
     }
 
     .sub-table {
         width: calc(100% - 25px) !important;
         border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
         border-left: 1px solid #ececec;
         border-right: 1px solid #ececec;
     }
 
     .sub-table-last-row {
         margin-bottom: 10px;
         border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec;
     }
 
     .download-btn {
         width: 10%;
         height: 70%;
     }
 
     .icon {
         width: 35px;
         height: 25px;
     }
 
     .export-btn:hover {
         width: 40px;
         height: 35px;
         margin-top: 10px !important;
         cursor: pointer;
     }
 
     .desc{
         width: 15%;
         padding-left: 20px;
         font-size: 1rem;
         border-top: 0;
     }
     .heldIn{
         width: 6%;
         word-wrap: break-word;
     }
     .w-q{
         width: 9%;
     }
     .account-name{
         width: 11%
     }
 
     th.currency-header:after {
         content: ' ($)';
         font-size: 1rem;
         top: 0;
         color:blue;
 
     }
```

```html
<div class="mt-3 card-title" role="region" aria-labelledby="yourTransactions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1 id="yourTransactions">Your Transactions</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col row justify-content-end">
            <img class="icon mt-3 mr-3 export-btn" alt="Export CSV" title="Export CSV" *ngIf="transactions?.length > 0" tabindex=0 (keyup.enter)="download('text/csv')" (click)="download('text/csv')"
                src="./assets/images/export_CSV.png" />
            <sh-accounts-dropdown class="m-2" [accounts]="dropdownOptions.types" (change)="setFilter('type', $event)"></sh-accounts-dropdown>
            <sh-accounts-dropdown class="m-2" [accounts]="dropdownOptions.accounts" (change)="setFilter('account', $event)"></sh-accounts-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table d-block m-0">
    <thead class="text-muted d-block col-12 float-left p-0 pr-1 w-100 table-header">
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell" (click)="transactionSorting('date');">
            Date <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('date')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell" (click)="transactionSorting('accountId');">
            Account #<i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('accountId')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell account-name" (click)="transactionSorting('accountNickName');">
            Account Nickname<i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('accountNickName')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell pr-2" (click)="transactionSorting('transaction');">
            Transaction Type <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('transaction')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell" (click)="transactionSorting('symbolcusip');">
            Symbol/CUSIP <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('symbolcusip')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell desc"  (click)="transactionSorting('description');">
            Description <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('description')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell heldIn" (click)="transactionSorting('heldin');">
            Held In <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('heldin')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left  text-right t-cell w-q"  (click)="transactionSorting('quantity');">
            Qty <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('quantity')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell text-right t-cell w-q" (click)="transactionSorting('price');">
            Price <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('price')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell text-right currency-header w-q" (click)="transactionSorting('amount');">
            Value <i [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('amount')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Use overflow:scroll for table parent div

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response , Can you breif your ans plz

Comment: make parent div for this class table d-block m-0. Then add css overflow:scroll for this parent div

Comment: I am little bit confused , If don't mine plz can you write that code here ?

Comment: Hi sagar Kodte , Can you plz help me in this.. Plz I am little bit confused .
Thanks in advnace

Comment: can you explain, Why you used `d-block` everywhere in table? If you want to display data in  table format  there is no need for that extra class

Comment: Ya but it actually written like that and I am new to this project...Can help me in this?? My rows and columns texts are overlapping with each other ...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="mt-3 card-title" role="region" aria-labelledby="yourTransactions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1 id="yourTransactions">Your Transactions</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col row justify-content-end">
            <img class="icon mt-3 mr-3 export-btn" alt="Export CSV" title="Export CSV" *ngIf="transactions?.length > 0" tabindex=0 (keyup.enter)="download('text/csv')" (click)="download('text/csv')"
                src="./assets/images/export_CSV.png" />
            <sh-accounts-dropdown class="m-2" [accounts]="dropdownOptions.types" (change)="setFilter('type', $event)"></sh-accounts-dropdown>
            <sh-accounts-dropdown class="m-2" [accounts]="dropdownOptions.accounts" (change)="setFilter('account', $event)"></sh-accounts-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table" style="overflow:scroll">
<table class="table d-block m-0">
    <thead class="text-muted d-block col-12 float-left p-0 pr-1 w-100 table-header">
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell" (click)="transactionSorting('date');">
            Date <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('date')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell" (click)="transactionSorting('accountId');">
            Account #<i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('accountId')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell account-name" (click)="transactionSorting('accountNickName');">
            Account Nickname<i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('accountNickName')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell pr-2" (click)="transactionSorting('transaction');">
            Transaction Type <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('transaction')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell" (click)="transactionSorting('symbolcusip');">
            Symbol/CUSIP <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('symbolcusip')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell desc"  (click)="transactionSorting('description');">
            Description <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('description')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell heldIn" (click)="transactionSorting('heldin');">
            Held In <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('heldin')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left  text-right t-cell w-q"  (click)="transactionSorting('quantity');">
            Qty <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('quantity')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell text-right t-cell w-q" (click)="transactionSorting('price');">
            Price <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('price')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
        <th class="d-block float-left t-cell text-right currency-header w-q" (click)="transactionSorting('amount');">
            Value <i [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('amount')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </th>
    </thead>
</table>
</div>
```

Update your code with above code

Comment: Hi sagar Kodte  , I updated but still my rows and columns texts are overlapping with each other ..... Need to do any changes in Css?